# How to fix error where a node in a tree is not being printed

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, binary-search-tree, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to insert 4 names into a bst. I have print statements that say where on the tree the name is passing through and then a print statement that outputs "null" when the name finds a valid spot. For example:

If the root is Dennis and the next node being inserted is Armin, it prints

left
null

However, when I try to print the tree in order, I'm missing a name.

I tried manually printing out the nodes, as in doing it like printf("%s", node->data); but I just get a segmentation fault.

The names I'm trying to print are apple, cris, dennis, loki. The output though is: apple, cris, loki. It always skips Dennis.

```
bstNode* insertNode(bstNode *root, char *data){

    if(root == NULL){
        printf("null, %s\n", data);

        root = newNode(data);
        return;
        }

    else if(wordSort(root->data, data) == -1){
        printf("right, %s\n", data);
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);
    }
    else if(wordSort(root->data, data) == 1){
        printf("left, %s\n", data);
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, data);
    }
}
```

```
  void printTree(bstNode *node){
//printf("%s\n", node->left->data);
//printf("%s\n", node->data);
//printf("%s\n", node->right->data);
//printf("%s\n", node->right->right->data);


 if (node == NULL)
          return;

     printTree(node->left);


     printf("%s\n", node->data);


     printTree(node->right);

}
```

```
bstNode* newNode(char *data){

bstNode* newnode = (bstNode*)malloc(sizeof(bstNode));
newnode->data =  (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(newnode->data, data);
newnode->left = NULL;
newnode->right = NULL;
strcpy(newnode->data, data);
newnode->count = 1;
return newnode;
}
```

Comment: The function bstNode* insertNode(bstNode *root, char *data){ returns nothing though has return type bstNode *.

Comment: `bstNode` is severely broken.  For example, if `root` is `NULL`, it will call `newNode`, assign the result to the local variable `root`, then return, discarding the new node and leaving the caller's root unchanged.  It's been declared to return a `bstNode *` but has been implemented as a (buggy) `void` function.  It needs to be fixed to return the new root node, always.

Comment: I'm currently running the program on PuTTY and thats where the code malfunctions, but when I plug in the same code into an online compiler it works perfectly. Any reason why and anyway I can fix it on PuTTY

Comment: The only way it might work is if the caller happens to pick up a stray value from a register (e.g. `root`) that is, in fact, the correct return value.  But you can't rely on this.  It's also a pointless mistake - just fix it.  Your compiler should have given multiple warnings for this code.  Always fix the warnings before asking for help.

Comment: Nevermind I see what you meant Tom. I fixed it and it works now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, glad you were able to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

The function `insertNode` has undefined behavior because it returns nothing though it has the return type `bstNode *`.

It can be defined and called the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct bstNode
{
    char *data;
    struct bstNode *left;
    struct bstNode *right;
} bstNode;

bstNode * newNode( const char *data )
{
    bstNode *node = malloc( sizeof( bstNode ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->left  = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;

        size_t n = strlen( data );
        node->data = malloc( n + 1 );

        if ( node->data != NULL )
        {
            strcpy( node->data, data );
        }
        else
        {
            free( node );
        }
    }

    return node;
}

bstNode * insertNode( bstNode *root, const char *data )
{
    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        root = newNode( data );
    }
    else if ( strcmp( root->data, data ) < 0 )
    {
        root->left = insertNode( root->left, data );
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = insertNode( root->right, data );
    }

    return root;
}

void printTree( const bstNode *root )
{
    if ( root != NULL )
    {
        printTree( root->left );
        puts( root->data );
        printTree( root->right );
    }
}
int main(void) 
{
    bstNode *root = NULL;

    root = insertNode( root, "pple" );
    root = insertNode( root, "cris" );
    root = insertNode( root, "dennis" );
    root = insertNode( root, "lok" );

    printTree( root );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
pple
lok
dennis
cris
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your logic. Please make sure you understand recursion well.
For example in the below statement you are pointing the root->right to nothing as when insertNode(root->right, data) statement executes it enters the first if block and then as the root is null it create a node with the given data but doesn't return any node.

`root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);`

That's why your program getting segmentation fault. What your program is doing is its is creating the nodes but not linking the nodes.